# symfony2 image add,edit,delete,caption text and change image order bundle

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload, bundle, symfony-2.3

Any bundle in symfony2 provide Image Uploads,Edit,Delete,Listing,change images order and image caption functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Please look at [Sonata Media Bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/index.html)